# ABP Suite seems to be generating code that will not compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-generation, abp

I was having trouble copying code from the EasyCrm sample project so I took Alper's advice and tried to generate all of my classes through the ABP Suite. Everything works pretty well until I get to the creation of a navigation property.

ABP Suite seems to be generating code that will not compile.

Here is the screenshot of the ABP Navigation properties page:

[image: Navigation properties page]

And here is the resulting error message:

[image: Error message]

And here is the CLI output:

[image: CLI output]

And here are the resulting build errors in Visual Studio:

[image: Errors in Visual Studio]

Please advise. Is this a bug? Should I just do the navigation properties on my own? Should I change out the AsQueryable() method call for another interface method?

Comment: Related: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/Abp-4_2

Comment: thanks for the feedback. this is already addressed and will be fixed in beta.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for reporting this issue. With Abp 5.0 Beta 1 version, the `IRepository` interface does not inherit from `IQueryable` anymore. I will create an internal issue for your problem.

In meantime, you can change the wrong lines as below

```cs
(await _countryRepository.GetQueryableAsync())
```